# java's ServerSocket in .net

Tags: c#, java, sockets

I've got a simple server (e.g. echo) written in Java. It uses ServerSocket class for networking purposes. 
I've got a client in C++. it uses WinSock2.h. (unfourtantly, I completely don't know C++)
They both run on one PC.

I'd like to use a C# server instead of Java one. It should be easy - In Java networking takes about one screen of code, so, I guess, it's not going to take more in C#.

I've never worked with networking applications before, so i don't have an idea what class and what preferences I should use in .net (instead of ServerSocket). 
I don't need a complete solution, but please, give me a clue.
I can provide any additional information if needed.

Thank u advance, sorry 4 my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [TcpListener Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx).

> **TcpListener Class**
>
> Listens for connections from TCP network clients.

MSDN has a complete example how to use set up a simple TCP server using this class.

Comment: Thank u much, this is EXACTLY what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.Net.Socket`